# How do I kill the giant spider?

Tags: luigis-mansion-dark-moon

In the Cellar of the first mansion, I can manage to hit the spider the first time, making her smash through the wall. Problem is, I have no idea what to do after that, with the fan and the burning net thing. I figure I have to get the web on fire again, but I can't seem to do it. What's the trick to it that I am missing?

Help! I don't want to die anymore!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to cut the web to allow you to pick up the ball and light it. You can cut it by using the sword statues.